# Facebook Marketing API JavaScript how to get Response Headers x-business-use-case-usage

Tags: javascript, facebook-marketing-api

Facebook's marketing API returns the following response headers when applying rate limiting due to too many calls:

```
x-business-use-case-usage: {"Account ID":[{"type":"ads_management","call_count":1,"total_cputime":10,"total_time":101,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":2}]}
```

How can I read these response headers with JavaScript?

I've tried `JSON.stringify(delCreative.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'])` but that doesn't pick up the particular header.

Reading just the headers `JSON.stringify(delCreative.headers` shows just the regular HTTP headers, but nothing specific from the Facebook marketing API.

Comment: What JavaScript run time are you using? What API are you making the HTTP request with? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: It's just running on my Chrome browser. It's the Facebook marketing API (as mentioned in the title and on the first line of my description). And it would be difficult to provide a reproducable example because the response headers will only show if you have a Facebook app token with ads management access ... I can't think of any other way to reproduce API response headers - is there one?

Comment: I'm making the delete requests via axios.delete - not sure if that helps clarify anything?